# Returning a dynamic list of items to my controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a table in my database, named PriceRanges:

```
PriceRanges
-----------------
PriceRangeID (PK)
RangeFrom
RangeTo
Price
```

I have a page where a user can add multiple price ranges, set up like so:

**[RangeFromTextbox] to [RangeToTextbox] - $[PriceTextbox]**

**[AddLink]**

So when "Add" is clicked, another row appears, and they can enter another price range.

In my view model, I have:

```
IEnumerable<PriceRange> PriceRanges { get; set; }
```

In my controller, when the user submits the form I'd like to do something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(MyViewModel viewModel)
{
    DBEntities entities = new DBEntities();

    foreach (PriceRange priceRange in viewModel.PriceRanges)
    {
        entities.AddToPriceRanges(priceRange);
    }

    entities.SaveChanges();
}
```

But I don't know how to relate a dynamic list of objects with my view model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may checkout the [following blog post](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/).